# Hibernate Validator @NotNull not working properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to make simple validation form using Hibernate Validator. I have two fields in my Customer class, and i want one of them to be required (lastName). 
The point is that even when im not filling this field I am not getting error message and BindingResult does not contain any errors. Is there anything im missing in my code?

Here is my Customer class snippet.

```
public class Customer {

    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "is required")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "is required")
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Here is Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    //adding new customer to model
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel){

        theModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());

        return "customer-form";
    }

    //Validating passed customer attribute/object
    //Biding result object holds validation results
    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer, BindingResult theBindingResult) {

        if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "customer-form";
        }

        return "customer-confirmation";
    }
}
```

EDIT: form code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
    .error{color: red}
</style>


<i> Fill out the form. Asteriks (*) means required. </i>
<br><br>
<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">

    First name: <form:input path="firstName" />

    <br><br>

    Last name (*): <form:input path="lastName"/>
    <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2:
I added to classpath validation-api.jar (contains the abstract API and the annotation scanner).

Also inserted @InitBinnder just to make sure that empty form field will always be null not empty String.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {

    StringTrimmerEditor stringTrimmerEditor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);

    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmerEditor);
}
```

But it still seems that those annotations never get triggered at all

EDIT 3: After calling validator on Entity I am getting error:

**org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.**

although i have added it to classpath

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
validator.validate(theCustomer);
```

EDIT 4: Adding Spring Configuration files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>mvc-validation-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-validation-demo.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-validation-demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lobo.mvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

EDIT 5: According to what @eis said i added to my mvc-validation-demo.xml:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalVa‌​lidatorFactoryBean"/‌​>
```

And i also have Hibernate Validator in my classpath:

[Classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dn5c.png)

but the error still remains

Comment: So, what is the value of the customer's lastName? What is its length?

Comment: I am not giving any value for it in my form. So the length is 0.

Comment: Do you *think* it is 0, or do you *know* it is 0 because you have printed the value of `theCustomer.getLastName().length()` and the output was 0? Have you enabled validation as explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring?

Comment: Do you have hibernate-validator-annotation-processor on your classpath?

Comment: check if the value is really null or an empty String. @NotBlank is probably the more fitting validator here.

Comment: @cproinger You were right, the form was aways returning empty String instead of null (fixed it by @InitBinder). But even now when Customer.getLastName is null, validation still doesn't work.

Comment: Add your validation form code as well

Comment: @SangamBelose code has been added in Edit.

Comment: @Mitsuomi where is your spring configuration, I don't see it in the question? how have you enabled the validator?

Comment: @Mitsuomi I would use `@NotEmpty`

Comment: @eis I have added my spring configuration Iam not sure if im missing anything. Antoniossss I tried almost all annotations, but as i mentioned before they just not getting triggerd.

Comment: @Mitsuomi according to your configuration, you haven't enabled the validator. It doesn't exist in your spring config. Like JB Nizet said, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring and notice `<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>` configuration you're missing

Comment: (in addition to that, you'd need hibernate validator in the classpath.)

Comment: @eis I was missing the bean declaration, but even after it's added the problem still remains (check EDIT5). Im already out of ideas what can cause it.

Comment: @Mitsuomi is hibernate-validator in your runtime classpath or just in your compile classpath? I suspect that you've added it to your compile classpath from your ide, but it is not getting deployed together with your application. Are you using Maven, gradle or similar dependency mechanism? can you confirm if hibernate validator gets packaged into your .war?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleteing .idea , clearing cache and new configuration did the job for me. It seems that somehow it didn't saw hibernate-validator.jar.

Thank you to everyone who contributed.